# What is the best practice way to update a Flask page with data from complex API calls?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have built a website to display some of a user's relevant info from the game Destiny 2. It is currently technically functional and displays the correct data, but since it is meant to run while the user plays the game, it needs to update the info that it presents to the user. Right now I have it reloading the page via jQuery every minute but I am looking for guidance on how to do this properly.

This is a Flask site that uses OAuth 2.0 and a little jQuery for additional functionality. The flow essentially is: user clicks "Authorize" button on home page -> redirected to Bungie's site to log in and authorize the app -> redirected back to my site with the relevant OAuth tokens/headers/etc. -> Python code makes a bunch of calls to Bungie's Destiny 2 API with the authorized tokens (in some cases getting more tokens to make further calls) -> grabs only the data it needs from those calls and formats it into a custom dictionary -> sends that to a Flask template -> template generates the required elements with Jinja based on the data passed to it. The character data that is shown is just the bounties and milestones for each character a user has, on any of the three gaming platforms. As a user completes objectives, I need the view to update the completion percentages. (Ex. "Collect resources from Mercury. 3/10")

As a quick and dirty solution I just have the page reloading itself, but this creates an annoying window of about 5-10 seconds where the page is loading and the user can't navigate any of the page buttons, followed by a noticeable flash when the page loads and elements pop back into view. This is obviously not acceptable, so I have considered some different options but I am unsure how to implement them in my specific scenario.

**AJAX**

This seems like the most obvious solution (I have never worked with it), but as far as I can tell it needs to make a call to a specific endpoint or API. Having AJAX make the API calls to Bungie rather than Flask seems unreasonable, since there are many calls to make and they need the OAuth tokens and sometimes need info from previous calls. I have considered having my Python code send its final dictionary of info to a new Flask endpoint that I create (rather than to a template), and then having AJAX make a call to that new endpoint to retrieve just the info it needs as JSON. To do this Flask would have to run the Python code in the background every minute while the user was on the page so the AJAX call would be getting up-to-date info. Would this create any security risks with sensitive player data being on an endpoint that you could just visit? Will this cause any conflicts with multiple users being logged in at the same time, all posting to that endpoint?

**Flask-SocketIO**

I don't know too much about this, but it seems like a great quick-response tool for server and client, but again I wonder if there will be security/conflict issues with multiple users being on at the same time?

**Flask Celery**

Again, I don't know much about this but it sounds like it could potentially work. Maybe have the API calls and data processing done in a background Celery task and sent to the template? But then how could that data be displayed seamlessly on the page (like AJAX) without a reload?

**JS Web Frameworks**

I have some experience with Angular which is why I included this section, since it displays new info and updates the page very smoothly. Could Angular controllers be used to store user data, then be updated behind the scenes which would automatically update the view? Could something like React or Vue be used here too?

Any help with choosing and using the best tool for this job would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to make asynchronous calls to your API. I probably recommend you to use a JS framework or AJAX for starters. Another recommendation would be to show your code and ask for help about something you are already working on, if not, it could seem like you are asking for someone to do your homework. Probably that's why you already have a negative vote. Hope this comment can help you

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with AJAX here, simply because it is the most widely used, and will therefore have the best documentation to refer to if you get stuck. You mention you are already using JQuery, which will make AJAX integration very easy. I'm sure searching "flask AJAX jquery" will give you some good results right off the bat.

I also recommend posting the relevant code you have so far (Flask endpoints/logic). It would definitely help people help you, and is generally good StackOverflow etiquette.

Comment: Yes I think I am going to go with AJAX since it seems like the most common thing for this type of updating. I have done plenty of looking into flask + ajax, but wasn't sure if I could use it for the complexity I need. Looks like I'll just have to make several ajax calls and do the data processing in jQuery rather than python! I know you're supposed to include code, but since I wasn't sure which way I should go for this I don't even have any relevant ajax code. This was more of a "what do you think would fit best?" question. I'll ask code questions once I start on the ajax. Thanks!